# Using a lightning-record-edit-form to show a form in modal to create record in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

How can i display error message that will come on submitting the form and also how will can we Handle creating a new record in lwc anyone has any examples ?

PS. I am using lightning-record-edit-form to bind the layout level required fields to show up correctly in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is fully addressed by the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation):

1. Errors can be captured by handling the error custom event. You can then display those in a [toast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation).
2. Creating records simply requires you not to pass an ID, just the object type.